# Deploying Flask app on AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i have been trying to deploy a flask app using EBS. I followed instructions from
[this link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Python_flask.html), but at the end i get [this](http://unbuffercom-master-env-ppvprpqmtr.elasticbeanstalk.com). Also is there any way i can ssh into my ebs volume as in other ec2 instances. Here is the link to the [aws log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2n7t3lgui675lbb/aws.log?dl=0). Also as an alternative how can i deploy my app without using ebs?

```
also my app structure is :

root folder/
              application.py
              requirements.txt
              uploads/
              modules/
                       static/
                       templates/
                       _init_.py
                       views.py
                       daemon_tasker.py
                       queue.py
                       json_play.py
                       find_detail.py
```

**Update**

Okay it might seem odd. But when i tried pip installing from requirements.txt in local machine it gives the same error, but if i pip install redis and six before pip installing from requirements.txt then no error is generated. Is there some way i can install redis and six before pip installing requirements.txt, or may be some setup script that can install retask after the pip install requirement.txt  is over?

Comment: It seems it's a problem during deployment.. "retask" requiere "redis" to build itself, and although redis it's installed correctly before, something it's happening here because Python can't import it during retask installing.

Comment: About if you can ask to the EC2 instance the answer is yes. Just go to EC2 control panel and there will be your instance(s). You'll can know how to connect these instances with the connect button up in the control panel (you need yo have a keyfile). It's important not to make permanent changes in ssh session because if a instance fall down this changes not gonna be there in the new created one (all instances configurations should be in a eb config file)..

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the problem in your logs. (You already identified it in the comments it seems).

```
  File "retask/queue.py", line 32, in <module>

    import redis

ImportError: No module named redis**strong text**
```

Do you have "redis==2.4.13" (or any other version) in your requirements.txt?

Also you are right that if you want to persist changes on all instances you should use ".ebextensions" config file.

Comment: Yes, he has (version 2.10.3), at the line: 17. According to aws logs it seems that it's installed (3 packages before than retask package installation) with this two warnings: `warning: no previously-included files found matching '__pycache__' warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found under directory 'tests'`